# Making a class discoverable for api server

Tags: python, class

I have set of tasks directory which has multiple tasks file like `task1.py`, `task2.py` every task has different class say `Task1` in task1.py and bunch of other dependent class, imports and this directory has some other files as well.

I want to create a mapping of this filename and the class object at runtime. What are the options do I have.

Adding base code

```
task_dict = {} # filename: task_object
def get_class_name():
    # Here I will do walk through tasks directory and 
    # find all the files that has task defined in it
    # and create a mapping which is like
    # {"task1": Task1, "task2": Task2}
```

task1.py will look like

```
import statements

Class Task1(CanInheritSomething):
    # some Code

class BunchOfOtherClass:
    pass

def some_random_method:
    pass
```

It's same for task2.

My question is what type of identification can be used to import Task1 class at runtime. I am still designing it so I am open with options

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-its-name-as-string