# Getting correct path to current script when running from exec()

Tags: python, exec

When I run one python file  from another python file by using exec(), the __file__ attribute is the caller's path not the callee:

file caller.py:

```
with open("callee.py", "r") as callee:
    exec(callee.read(), globals(), locals())
```

file callee.py:

```
print("this file is:", __file__)
```

result printed is:

```
this file is: caller.py
```

instead of the expected:

```
this file is: callee.py
```

How can I get the path to the currently executed file even when the file is being exec()'ed ?

Comment: `callee.read()` returns text that is then passed to `exec()`. Conceptually no different than `exec("print('hello')")`. I think you are potentially looking to `import callee`.

Comment: @JonSG: I reduced the problem to the minimum required to ask the question. The real code I'm working on is loading files on demand and executing them. So, no, import callee will not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import a module dynamically given its name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-its-name-as-string)