# python importlib.import_module into current scope

Tags: python, python-import

I'm following in a long line of people struggling with `importlib` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-its-name-as-string), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-the-full-path)) (I have also [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)).

I want to import all the elements in a list into the current scope as if I had done `import my_package1; import my_package2' ...`. The problem is that `importlib.import_module(module)` returns the module rather than adding it to the scope so it can be used. I am trying to expose submodules which is why I don't want them in a variable

Comment: this isn't going to be possible in local scopes, you cannot dynamically create local variables

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I figured it out (see answer below). It comes down to creating the module as a local attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I figured out is that you can set `sys.module` attributes. For published modules this takes the form

```
import importlib, sys

module = 'os'
module_handle = importlib.import_module(module)    
setattr(sys.modules[__name__], module, module_handle)

os.getenv('SHELL')

'/bin/bash'
```

For local packages (the use case I'm interested in) you need to do define `module_handle` a bit differently by specifying the `package` option

```
module_handle = importlib.import_module('.' + module, __name__)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how does this do what you asked for? This doesn't import something into the current scope. This just puts it into the global scope. If you wanted to do that, you could just do `globals()[module] = importlib.import_module(module)`

Comment: This isn't a "local attribute", `sys.modules[__name__]` is just a complicated way of getting `globals()`

Comment: It's in the scope of the module as if I did an import. I didn't say I wanted a local variable. I'm sorry if I didn't use the correct terminology that led to you misunderstanding my ask