# Importing a dictionary from a python file who's name is only known at runtime

Tags: python, python-module

I'm currently making a system that allows users to write a dictionary in new .py files(which are created in a seperate folder in the same directory) and then access that dictionary. I have the creating and file writing part working, but the problem arises when trying to access the dictionary in a file specified by the user. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Here's the hierarchy:
Python(working directory)
|
|---Test(project folder)
         |
         |---main.py(the main project code)
         |
         |---SubFolder(where the .py files with each having a dictionary are stored)
                |
                |---Test.py, etc.
```

I tried using import __ from __, __ import __(ignore the spaces) and importlib.util. None of these ended up working as it would just give me an import error

Comment: It's possible to import a module given it's name as string, but more convinient would be to ask user to create a JSON file and just read it

Comment: The problem is that the module is in another folder and, which I would usually do 
`from folder.module import dictionary`
that doesn't work in this case because the file name is unknown before runtime

Comment: The module should be in such location that is in python's module search path. Using JSON (or other standard format), not module for such task would be the common approach

Comment: See [How can I import a module dynamically given its name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/301134/4046632) but again, better approach is to use JSON. That's why I don't close this as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, importlib

# ...

sys.path.append(directory_with_file)
module_with_user_dict = importlib.import_module(filename_without_py_extension)
module_with_user_dict.dict_name
```

Keep in mind you are then allowing user to execute arbitrary code so it is not so great idea.

(I would recommend to let an user to provide a JSON file instead as @buran suggests in comments.)

Comment: Thanks! What I'm aiming to do is letting the user create the dictionary and file just by providing the contents of the dictionary in a command prompt using input().

Comment: @ObSp, _What I'm aiming to do is letting the user create the dictionary and file just by providing the contents of the dictionary in a command prompt using input()._ - now this sounds different (opposite) from your original question.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that they could write it and then access it. Using .py files also allow me to directly import the dictionary from that file instead of having to convert it from a string into a dictionary. Feel free to correct me here, though, since I'm a beginner.

Comment: Using [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to deserialize the JSON file congaing jsonobject gives you a dict. really have a look at it and you will see it's way more common. Depending on what data represent there may be even better formats