# How to get string from another python file and import it into function of different file?

Tags: python

I have a two files; "extraction" and "main" what I want to do is paste into a function of "main" from "extraction".

So if in extraction.py there is a assignment that looks like this

```
A = "123"
```

then in main.py I want to use that assignment in a function so something like

```
 exportData(extraction.A)
```

and hopefully this will be the equivalent of

```
 exportData("123")
```

By doing this I can hopefully have lots of extraction files (extraction1, extraction2 etc) that produce strings and then they will be run with exportData function and the people creating the extraction files wont need to go into main.py function and potentially break it.

Comment: It will be like you hope it would be. So what was the problem?

Comment: In your `main.py`, do `from extraction import A` this will make A available in `main.py` if that's what you mean to achieve

Comment: And if you plan to import variable modules as you seem to imply, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-its-name-as-string

Answer (score 0):

You just have to import the A into main file like this.

```
# extraction.py

A = "123"
```

```
# main.py
from extraction import A

def exportData(data):
    print(f"Exporting data: {data}")

exportData(A)
```

or you can import whole file

```
# main.py
import extraction

def exportData(data):
    print(f"Exporting data: {data}")

exportData(extraction.A)
```